# How do I merge column values into a column of vectors based on unique row values?

Tags: r

I'm new to R so would be grateful for your help to understand what is going on!
I have a dataframe that is very big, the structure looks like this:

Var1    Var2
(chr)   (int)
A ,   1 
A ,  2 
A  , 3 
B  , 4 
B  , 5 
C  , 6 
C  , 7 
C  , 8 
C  , 9 
...

I want to create a new dataframe that groups the Var 1 categorical values together, and all the corresponding integer Var2 values into numerical vectors

I am hoping it looks like:
Var1 Var2_Combined
(chr) (int)
A , vector[1, 2, 3]
B , vector[4, 5]
C , vector[6, 7, 8, 9]
*etc.*

Because the dataset is large, i don't want to assign each vector manually and i want to do it through a function. I've tried the following, but it hasn't worked.

**1. Convert to string**

```
write.csv(aggregate(df$Var2 ~ df$Var1, FUN = toString), file = "Test_file")
```

but i couldn't convert the string back into useable numerics using as.numeric() or as.integer() or any of these types of commands.

**2. Concatenate**
I tried to do it with the c()

```
write.csv(aggregate(df$Var2 ~ df$Var1, FUN = c), file = "Test_file")
```

While it match up all the Var2 values to unique values in Var1, it created a bunch of new columns rather than a column combining those values into vectors:

Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 *etc*
(chr) (int) (int) (int) *etc*
A , 1 , 2 , 3 *etc*
B , 1 , 2 , 3 *etc*

**3. a for loop**

I tried to use the unique() filter and a 'for' loop, but it just returned unusable numbers

```
Var1_Unique <- unique(df$Var1)    
Var2_Combined <- numeric(length = length(Var1_Unique))    

for (i in seq(1, length(Var1_Unique))) {         
   Var2_Combined[i] <- df %>% filter(Var2 == Var1_Unique[i]) 
   }
```

I only have dplyr attached at the moment.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options :

**1. Store the data in a list.**

A. Using base R :

```
df1 <- aggregate(Var2~Var1, df, list)
df1

#  Var1       Var2
#1    A    1, 2, 3
#2    B       4, 5
#3    C 6, 7, 8, 9

str(df1)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Var1: chr  "A" "B" "C"
# $ Var2:List of 3
#  ..$ : int  1 2 3
#  ..$ : int  4 5
#  ..$ : int  6 7 8 9
```

Now get the data back as original.

```
df2 <- transform(df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), lengths(df1$Var2)), ], 
                 Var2 = unlist(df1$Var2))
str(df2)
#'data.frame':  9 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Var1: chr  "A" "A" "A" "B" ...
# $ Var2: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

B. Using `tidyverse`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df %>% group_by(Var1) %>% summarise(Var2 = list(Var2))
df2 <- df1 %>% unnest(Var2)
```

---

**2. Store the data as a string.**

A. Using base R

```
df1 <- aggregate(Var2~Var1, df, toString)
str(df1)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Var1: chr  "A" "B" "C"
# $ Var2: chr  "1, 2, 3" "4, 5" "6, 7, 8, 9"
```

Get it back to original format.

```
tmp <- strsplit(df1$Var2, ', ')
df2 <- transform(df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), lengths(tmp)),], 
                 Var2 = as.numeric(unlist(tmp)))
str(df2)
#'data.frame':  9 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Var1: chr  "A" "A" "A" "B" ...
# $ Var2: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

B. Using `tidyverse` :

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(Var1) %>% summarise(Var2 = toString(Var2))
df2 <- df1 %>% separate_rows(Var2, sep = ', ', convert = TRUE)
```

---

You can use both the options if you want to keep the data in R only. If you want to write intermediate results to csv for `df1` you cannot use option 1 because `write.csv` would not be able to write list columns to csv in which case you need to use option 2.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect! Your answer 1.A. is exactly what i was looking for. It was so easy to create a list, i'm embarrassed i didn't think of it. Thank you so much again!